# Which LEGO set did this bags 4 - 10 with castle pieces come from?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

I have bags 4-10 of 2011 LEGO group 135149.  I'm trying to find what set they are from. At first I thought maybe a castle due to the doors. 
I have pictures:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Bags 5 till 10 are from 
[70404-1: King's Castle](https://brickset.com/sets/70404-1/King-s-Castle)

[image]

based on [Ladder](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6079814) and [Staircase 7X4X6](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4277751) in Reddish Brown.

It also contain the *Plate 4X4* in green, and the door and wall pieces.

Bag 4 is from [9526-1: Palpatine's Arrest](https://brickset.com/sets/9526-1/Palpatine-s-Arrest)

[image]

Based on [Corner Plate 6X6X45°](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4211520) in Medium Stone Grey and [Brick 1X2 M. 2 Holes Ø 4,87](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4201615) in Bright Yellow.

It also contain the red 2x6 and grey  1x8 technic pieces

Answer (score 1):

Looks mostly from  [*Set # 70404 King's Castle*](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=70404-1). Minus bag No.4.

[image]